# How to join the same 2 models twice in Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm on rails 4 and I couldn't figure out how to join two models twice in rails. I found [an answer to my problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196058/how-can-i-join-the-same-2-models-twice-in-rails) but it's an old one, here's what it says:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_countries
  has_many :event_countries,
    :through => :user_countries,
    :source => :country,
    :conditions => { :event => true }
  has_many :research_countries,
    :through => :user_countries,
    :source => :country,
    :conditions => { :research => true }
end

class UserCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user

  # * column :event, :boolean
  # * column :research, :boolean
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end
```

I found this solution interesting as I only need one join table for UserCountries, however it doesn't seem to work in rails 4 ([the conditions method has been deprecated in rails 4.0](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ThroughReflection/conditions)), so my question is simply : how would you do this in rails 4.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you mention is still valid, you just need to change the conditions part to adopt the new Rails 4 convention (see [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307874/what-is-the-equivalent-of-conditions-in-has-many-rails-4)):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_countries
  has_many :event_countries,
    -> { where(user_countries: {:event => true}) },
    :through => :user_countries,
    :source => :country
  has_many :research_countries,
    -> { where(user_countries: {:research => true}) },
    :through => :user_countries
    :source => :country
end

class UserCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer however it looks like it tried to get the event column in the countries table: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: countries.event: SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" INNER JOIN "user_countries" ON "countries"."id" = "user_countries"."country_id" WHERE "countries"."event" = 't' AND "user_countries"."user_id" = ?

Comment: Indeed there are two things missing in your answer:
- -> { where(user_countries: { event: true } }
- :source => country

Comment: This is working:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_countries
  has_many :event_countries,
    -> { where(user_countries: {:event => true})},
    :through => :user_countries
    :source => :country
  has_many :research_countries,
    -> { where(user_countries: {:research => true})},
    :through => :user_countries
    :source => :country
end

class UserCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end


You can edit so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @Badoo thanks for testing it, I wrote it from the top of my head. Code fixed. Glad to help!